# supervisor or nohup command is better to run a process in the background

Tags: linux

I have a long running PHP script with heavy load. I have two options to run this in background. Either to use `nohup` command or to use supervisor.

Are these same ? if not which one is better for heavy load scripts ?

Note: The script is an MQTT subscriber to receive and process data from 25,000 IoT devices.

Comment: "I have two options". Those are the two you know, or are you forced to use one of them? I ask because the obvious approach would be using SystemD.

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor is a service supervisor program, that is able to monitor and control a service. It can start the service on boot and restart the service when it fails.

Nohup is something completely different: Normally when you log out, all the processes you have started from your shell will get terminated. Nohup prevents that behaviour.

In your case supervisor is a good choice to setup your process, start, restart and control it.